# Translating Fortran DLL to VB.NET DLL

Tags: vb.net, dll, fortran, fortran77

**Core Question:** If I can't change the calling procedure from the calling program, can I still translate the original source code of a DLL from Fortran 77 to VB.Net? I.e., Is it possible to make a DLL written in VB.NET behave identically to one that its source code was originally written in Fortran 77?

I know I'll run into problems with strings. But none of my procedures will have input/outputs of strings, only 4-byte integers and 8-byte doubles.

I have to modify a DLL written originally in Fortran 77. To make any future changes easier, I would like to translate the DLL source code from Fortran to VB.Net. I can't modify the program that calls the DLL, and I don't have the code for the program that calls the DLL so I don't know how it's calling it. First of all, is what I'm trying to do possible? I would think it is since a DLL is a DLL regardless of the source language, no? This is where I'm at:

The Fortran source code looks like this:

```
    subroutine init(dwid)

    use dfport
    implicit none
    common /fltcmn/ ifirst, icnt
    integer ifirst, icnt
    integer(4) dwid
    external fndndx
cDEC$ ATTRIBUTES C, REFERENCE, DLLEXPORT, ALIAS:'_INIT' :: INIT

    [code in here w/ return]

    end subroutine init


    function fndndx(dwid)

    use dfport
    implicit none
    common /fltcmn/ ifirst, icnt
    integer ifirst, icnt, fndndx
    integer(4) dwid

    [code in here w/ return]

    end function fndndx
```

And now follows my attempt to translate it (which right now it's not working)

```
    Public Class Class1
        Public ifirst as Integer
        Public icnt as Integer

        Sub init(ByVal dwid as Integer)

            [Code in here w/ return]

        End Sub

        Function fndndx(ByVal dwid as Integer) as Integer

            [Code in here w/ return]

        End Function

    End Class
```

I'm pretty confident the [code in here w/ return] is correct since it's basic logical statements. However, what I'm not sure is if I'm dealing with the Fortran "common" statements correctly, and if it's OK to have the functions and subroutines inside a "Class"...

Comment: You say, "to make future changes easier". But which is more likely to have a future, and to be widespread? Fortran, or VB? VB was born in 1991. Fortran managed to survive 40 more years, is an actively improved standard (Fortran 66, 77, 90, 95, 2003, 2008 and the upcoming 2015), there are many compilers to count on, not just one, and there are good free compilers (gfortran, open64)... Oh, and by the way, if it's a DLL, it may also be linked to VB as well as anything, not much need to translate.

Comment: Are you saying that this is the original FORTRAN source and that "[Code in here w/ return]" compiles and actually does something? Well... it has been a while since the last time I coded in FORTRAN but I am under the impression that this code does not do anything. Regarding the Classes, this is not a deal at all; they are mere containers which, in the worst scenario, you would have just to include in your calls.

Comment: @arbautjc I meant easier for users like me, with more experience with vb.net. As much as I want to become more fluent in Fortran, time is only so much. The code is not solving math problems, but logical statements resulting in actions in a program, which in my opinion VB is a little more user friendly in that aspect.

Comment: @arbautjc nice words but you don't seem to have tried to adapt a program done completely in FORTRAN to nowadays OS, programs, etc. Not to mention the small detail of not having any kind of support/interface capabilities. It is a nice calculating engine, perhaps the best one (precisely because of not having absolutely anything other than the basics), but cannot be used automously, at least, not at a commercial level. On the other hand, you have the unpleasant reality of having to code without any kind of visual help when working on more or less complex projects.

Comment: @varocarbas Did I left out some important statements? I tried making a representative short example of my problem. The original Fortran code when compiled as a DLL works as expected. The Fortran source code has routines that are called by another program. The routines have specific names with known input/output data type/length.

Comment: @varocarbas. I think you have not seen Fortran for a long time. Who is asking for autonomous programs? Here Esteban wants a DLL, which is not much autonomous I believe. With ISO_C_BINDING it's not a real problem to interface, nowadays (and in case you are in doubt, the above code is in Fortran 90).

Comment: You left out everything. This is just the declaration of a bunch of variables; but you are not doing anything with them, so... But I don't think that you can post here whole codes and ask for a conversion. You should be able to come up with most of it and ask about specific issues. In case of not having too much experience, just convert line by line everything in the original code until you reach a point which you cannot deal with and then would be the point to ask here (to someone more knowledgeable than myself).

Comment: @esteban. If the Fortran code does not do "number crunching", you are right, it may be a good idea to translate. COMMON variables are shared between program units that use them. It's like global variables, so I think using class variables is ok (my VB is bad, but if I'm right here they are instance variables, so they will only be shared between methods, not between objects).

Comment: @varocarbas, I guess my biggest question is if the structure is correct. Like I mentioned, the [code] is quite straight forward to translate. It's just that the program that reads the routines from the dll is not finding the routines.

Comment: @arbautjc, I think you're addressing some of my confusions. Yes, there will be multiple instances of the "dll" which the Main program manages with the "dwid" variable I have mentioned (I'm not sure if I'm describing this correctly). What would be the vb.net equivalent to variables that are shared between instances of a dll? (if there is one?)

Comment: Hem, you mean instances of a class (i.e. objects), not instances of a DLL? Even in Fortran (because it does actually depend on the OS), if two programs load the same DLL, their adress space are not merged, unless you use special tricks.

Comment: @arbaujtc Yes, instances of an object.

Comment: @varocarbas, so if I can't change the calling program, I can't change the source language of the DLL? There's no way to make an "identical" Dll from Fortran and Vb.net?

Comment: When you call a DLL you have to follow certain rules (and the target app has to support the language, in this case, .NET). Also you have the problem of the differences between FORTRAN (which, presumably, includes just the functions directly) and VB.NET which has Namespace (and then Class); all this might have to be accounted for by the calling program. If you don't have access to the calling program (unless it is built in .NET), perhaps you shouldn't convert the library.

Comment: Identical, I am afraid that it is impossible. With VB.NET you bring all the .NET framework into account (something which FORTRAN does not have). You can do a quick research by looking for ways to call a DLL built in language X from language Y; there are always different bits and pieces. And when dealing with .NET, .NET has to be supported. On the other hand, it does not need to be identical because the calling program might support both (and you might come up with a way to compensate the differences). But not having access to the source of the calling program is certainly a problem.

Comment: Just keep it simple: what is the first thing you have to do when calling a DLL in .NET (from .NET)? Adding the reference/the namespace, this is the most visible bit of any .NET program. FORTRAN does not have that. Just forget about all the other potential problems, how can you calling program know now that it has to include a Namespace? So far, it was doing: "init" and now it should be doing "NameSpace.init" or add reference to Namespace + init... Just this bit is relevant. See it in this other way: imaging a program loading a file to run, what happens if you change the file name?

Comment: Lastly, I want insist in the fact that I haven't ever tried this (and, honestly, not feeling like doing it now); and I am not saying that there is no workaround. What I am saying is that, a priori, there might be quite a few problems (which might be avoided/reduced in case of having access to the source of the calling program) and that what the calling program supports/can deal with do matter.

Comment: @varocarbas, I'm afraid that's the problem that I'm running into. That the program is calling init rather than Class1.init. The calling program I'm dealing with is a small company proprietary program that is still under development [but with old remnants], so there's not much documentation on things. Thanks for the leads and help!

Comment: @arbautjc, thanks for the comments and help!

Comment: You could try building your F77 code with something like the Silverfrost compiler which has a .net interface and use the dll that it generates.

Comment: Have a look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817248.  That is for VB.net DLLs used in VB6.  This will be similar to using DLLs in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is "you can't do this."  As far as I can tell, the DLL you show is getting info back to the main program by changing variables in a common block.  But .NET doesn't have that.